# Run a spec specified by line number through Guard

Tags: ruby, rspec, guard

using option --line I can do the following

```
spec spec/controller/my_controller_spec.rb -l 34 # test block at line 34 only will be run
```

How can I do the same if I am using guard and don't want to run all the tests in a spec file ?

Is there an option in Guard file to accept line number and have the Guard only run that test ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the :cli option in your Guardfile.

```
guard 'rspec', :cli => "-l 34"
```

You can use any of the standard rspec command line options using :cli.  For more information please check [guard-rspec readme](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) (about halfway down the page)